# no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(34, 53) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(AllStores,ListView,Response<List<Store>>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual argument ListView cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual argument ListView cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual argument ListView cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                AllStores.this,
                lv,
                subprises);
```

I have also tried to replace the first parameter of `ArrayAdapter` with `this`, `getApplicationContext()` or `context`. Unfortunately it didn't worked. I have really no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here below you can see my code if you want to see it:

AllStores.java:

```
public class AllStores extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_stores);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.store_list);
        Response<List<Store>> subprises;
        try {
            subprises = new StoreService().getSubprises();
            Iterator it = subprises.body().iterator();
            ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    AllStores.this,
                    lv,
                    subprises);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to pass an `Object` of `Response<List<Store>>` in an `ArrayList` of `String`...You have to create your own adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter` and then make it like this. The default constructor requires `Context`, layoutId, `StringArray`...

Comment: you can ssee the implementation of a custom adapter [here](http://www.greektutorials.com/en/projects/advanced-listview-with-images-and-text.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ArrayAdapter<String>` constructor doesn't accept `ListView` nor `Response<List<Store>>` and in your code you added them both

```
ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> AllStores.this, lv, subprises);
```

but it should take the `Context`, `layout resource id` and the `List<String>` or `String[]`. A simple adapter would be

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AllStores.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_string_array_or_list);
```

then you set that adapter to your `ListView`

```
lv.setAdapter(adatper);
```

If you want more complex adapter, you should create a custom `ArrayAdapter`. Check out this link
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter