# Error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(activity, int, int, string)

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have been wanted to display multiple data retrieve in a list view. However when i used array adapter, i have been facing this problem. How should i solve it? This is the class where i get my data and i store it in an array list. The array list will later be call in another class to put it in array adapter.

```
public class connect2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";
View view;
Activity activity;
public static final String SEARCH = "product_img1";
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

ContactObjects co = new ContactObjects();

Bitmap bitmap;

public connect2(Activity activity, View v) {
    this.activity = activity;
    view = v;
}


String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String ipAddress = "http://192.168.43.214/apexStore2/";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(ipAddress +"image1.php");
        String urlParameters =
                URLEncoder.encode("cat_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + 
 URLEncoder.encode(arg0[0], "UTF-8") + "&" +
                      URLEncoder.encode("product_img1", "UTF-8") + "=" + 
 URLEncoder.encode("???", "UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
 url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        //System.out.println(response.toString());

        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray uniObject = mainObject.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i = 0; i < uniObject.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject rowObject = uniObject.getJSONObject(i);
            //EventObject co = new EventObject();
            co.img1 = ipAddress +"img/products/" + 
  rowObject.getString("product_img1");
            //mContentItems.add(co);
            System.out.println("hi" +co.title);
            list.add(co.img1);
        }

        //To further break down JSON
        //JSONObject oneObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("1");
        //String id = oneObject.getJSONObject("id");
        try{

        }
        finally{
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return "";
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CatalogActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(SEARCH, list);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}


private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    ImageView img;
    public LoadImage(ImageView img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new 
  URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

        if(image != null){
            img.setImageBitmap(image);
        }else{
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the class where i call the data and put it in array adapter.

```
public class CatalogActivity extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catalog);

    // Create the list
    ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) 
findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
    setContentView(R.layout.item);
    new connect2 (this, 
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).execute("3");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String search = intent.getStringExtra(connect2.SEARCH);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, 
R.id.ImageViewItem, search);
    listViewCatalog.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376361/no-suitable-constructor-found-for-arrayadapter

Comment: However the solution of that source did not solve my problem.

Comment: May be you need to create your own `Array Adapter Constructor` for this which contains required parameters you want.

Comment: Did you confirm `ArrayAdapter` is added in imports?

Comment: yes i have imported "import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;"

Comment: is the constructor something like this "public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)" ?

Comment: @CheongCharlene Yes exactly. and Also take last parameter as your search data.

Comment: @CheongCharlene Make sure one thing why you are using multiple `setContentView` is their any reason please specify.

Comment: There is only 1 setContentView, setContentView(R.layout.item); is not valid, i already cancel it off

Comment: should the constructor be created in a different class? the constructor is something like public ArrayAdapter (CatalogActivity.this, R.layout.item, R.id.TextViewItem). what do you mean by take my last parameter as my search data?

Comment: @CheongCharlene Means currently what your question's `Array Adapter` contains last parameter that you can also include.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're using an `ImageView`'s resource ID while `ArrayAdapter` takes only `TextView` as resource ID.

**EDIT**- Since your string is nothing but text, the container can't be an `ImageView`.

**Another EDIT**- You need to pass a `List` of strings as a parameter as the 4th parameter. Add this as the 4th parameter instead:- new String[]{search}

Comment: even though i substitude with this  "String product_title = intent.getStringExtra(connect2.SEARCH1);  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CatalogActivity.this, R.layout.item, R.id.TextViewItem, product_title);" it give me the same error as well. Both imageview and textview cant display.

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace of the error? @CheongCharlene

Comment: Error:(34, 19) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(CatalogActivity,int,int,String)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual argument String cannot be converted to List<String> by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual argument String cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @CheongCharlene updated, this should solve your problem.

Comment: @CheongCharlene Please paste the stacktrace always when you get such errors. The answer is within them.